# WordPress- Calling a function - not working when using custom tag

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, tags

The following function works by adding it to >the_content() , however, I want to display it at a custom location in my html markup via a custom tag, when I tried this I got a PHP error, I'm sure this is something very simple but I for the life of me cannot see the issue.

```
  // code from crunchify
 function supersun_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    global $post;
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL
        $supersunURL = urlencode(get_permalink());

        // Get current page title
        $supersunTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $supersunThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$supersunTitle.'&amp;url='.$supersunURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$supersunURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$supersunURL;
        $whatsappURL = 'whatsapp://send?text='.$supersunTitle . ' ' . $supersunURL;
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$supersunURL.'&amp;media='.$supersunThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$supersunTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $variable .= '<div class="supersun-social">';
        $variable .= '<a class="supersun-social-link supersun-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="supersun-social-link supersun-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="supersun-social-link supersun-whatsapp" href="'.$whatsappURL.'" target="_blank" title="Share on Whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="supersun-social-link supersun-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="supersun-social-link supersun-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank" title="Share on Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $variable .= '</div>';

        return $variable.$content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $variable.$content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'supersun_social_sharing_buttons');
```

THIS ERROR MESSAGE APPEARS WHEN I ADD 
    `<?php supersun_social_sharing_buttons(); ?>`
TO MY THEME.

[image]

Thank you so much for your time. Sorry the site is not currently live, I think this should be an easy fix for someone with an experienced eye.

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
 *
 * @package FoundationPress
 * @since FoundationPress 1.0.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="post-container">
 <div class="blog-single-header-background" id="blog-single-header-background">
 </div>
  <?php supersun_social_sharing_buttons($content); ?>
 <div class="container post-content-container">
  <div class="columns medium-10 medium-centered">
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="single-blog-post" role="main">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <article <?php post_class('main-content') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <header class="post-header">
       <h1 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

       <div class="post-author-details">

        <a href="<?php get_the_author_link(); ?>" class="post-author-avatar image-circle float-left">
         <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 64 ); ?>
        </a>

        <div class="post-author-meta media-body margin-left">

         <h4 class="author-post-byline">
          <span> By </span>
          <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
           <span itemprop="name" class="author-post-link"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
          </span>
          <span class="post-date">
           on <?php echo the_time("M j, Y");?>
          </span>
         </h4>

         <span class="post-meta-wrap">
           <span class="post-category">
            <span class="pre-cat"> In
            </span>
            <?php $categories = get_the_category();
            if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
            }?>
           </span>
         </span>

        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
      </header>



      


      <div class="post-content">
       <span itemprop="articleBody">
        <div class="post-image">
         <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
       </span>
      </div>

      <footer>
       <div class="post-author-about-section">

        <?php
         global $post;

         // Detect if it is a single post with a post author
         if ( is_single() && isset( $post->post_author ) ) {

         // Get author's display name
         $display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );

         // If display name is not available then use nickname as display name
         if ( empty( $display_name ) )
         $display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post->post_author );

         // Get author's biographical information or description
         $user_description = get_the_author_meta( 'user_description', $post->post_author );

         // Get author's website URL
         $user_website = get_the_author_meta('url', $post->post_author);

         // Get link to the author archive page
         $user_posts = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' , $post->post_author));



         if ( ! empty( $user_description ) )
         // Author avatar and bio

        $author_details = '<a href="' . $user_posts . '" class="author-about-avatar">' . get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email') , 90 ) . '</a>';

        $author_details .= '<div class="media-body margin-left">';

        if ( ! empty( $display_name ) )

         // $author_details = '<p class="author-about-name">About ' . $display_name . '</p>';

        $author_details .= '<h4 class="author-post-byline author-about-name">';
        $author_details .= '<span class="pre-author-header"> About </span>';
        $author_details .= '<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">';
        $author_details .= '<span itemprop="name" class="author-post-link"><a href="' . $user_posts . '">' . $display_name . '</a></span>';
        $author_details .= '</span>';
        $author_details .= '</h4>';

         $author_details .= '<p class="author-about-details">' . nl2br( $user_description ). '</p>';

         // $author_details .= '<p class="author-about-links"><a href="'. $user_posts .'">View all posts by ' . $display_name . '</a>';

         // Check if author has a website in their profile
         if ( ! empty( $user_website ) ) {

         // Display author website link
         $author_details .= ' | <a href="' . $user_website .'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Website</a></p>';

         } else {
         // if there is no author website then just close the paragraph
         $author_details .= '</p>';
         }

        $author_details .= '</div">';

         // Pass all this info to post content
         $content = $content . $author_details;
         }
         echo $content;
        ?>


       </div>



      </footer>

     </article>
   </div>
   <?php endwhile;?>



   <div class="related-posts">
    <?php $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    if ($tags) {
    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
    $args=array(
    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=>2, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<div id="relatedposts"><h3>Related Posts</h3>';

    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="columns medium-6 large-6 collapse margin-bottom">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <div class="related-post-item content-card">

       <div class="related-thumb">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
       </div>

       <div class="related-content">

        <div class="related-category-title">
         <?php $categories = get_the_category();
           if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
             echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );
           }?>
        </div>

        <h2>
         <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>

       </div>

      </div>
     </a>

     </div>

    <?php }
    echo '</div>';
    }
    }
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
   </div>

   <div class="clear"> </div>

   <!-- <h3> Comments </h3> -->

   <div class="comments">
    <?php do_action( 'foundationpress_post_before_comments' ); ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'foundationpress_post_after_comments' ); ?>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Can you read the error that you get? What does it say? "missing..."?

Comment: Yes, excuse my inexperience, I'm not entirely sure what it means? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need pass a parameter when you call your function directly, not in `add_filter`. Like this `<?php supersun_social_sharing_buttons($parameter); ?>`

Comment: I see, but what would the parameter be in this case? Sorry if i'm coming across as dumb, i'm still learning - I tried $content, but this didn't work

Comment: You function gets parameter, transfroms it (or not) and returns back. When you call it from `add_filter`, parameter is a content of post. When you call it directly you have to pass some parameter by your own. For example:
`<?php $text = 'some data';
$changed_text = supersun_social_sharing_buttons($text); ?>`

Comment: Ah okay, but does the parameter have to be specific? I mean in my brain I want to called $content because that's the content of my function, what would i replace 'some data' with in order to get my functions content to show?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achive. If your code is valid calling `add_filter( 'the_content', 'supersun_social_sharing_buttons');` is enough for applying it to your theme. There is no need to call it again. If you don't see content changes find trubles in function)

Comment: well I want to display it in a place in my markup other that 'the_content' - i was hoping to create a custom tag and slot it in when and where I needed it... is this achievable?

Comment: can you show your markup? the place where you calling function

Comment: Okay, I've added the markup, thank you so much for your time, really appreciate this!

Comment: When you use this filter `add_filter( 'the_content', 'supersun_social_sharing_buttons');` it means that your function will be applied in this row `<?php the_content(); ?>`. As I said earlier if you don't see content changes find reasons in your function or make sure that filter applied.

As a hotfix you can get the content of post and pass it to your function and echo the result:
`<?php $content = get_the_content();
 echo supersun_social_sharing_buttons($content); ?>`. But you can do this ONLY IN LOOP (after this row `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`)

Comment: Interesting! So what's to stop me creating a new loop specifically to call this function? Is that good practice? Or even possible? Because then surely I could place it anywhere?

Comment: No, that isn't good practice) A good practice for wordpress is don't change original theme/core files and add all your code within your own plugins and child themes, hooks and filters. Specifically these links for social networks you can also add using widget or shortcode. Read more about wordpress :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it is working how I wanted now and I didn't need to use a second loop, I will read more about hooks and filters, looks really interesting, thanks so much.